# Кто такая "венеричка"?

Tags: лексика

В известном стихотворении Саши Чёрного ["Городская сказка"](http://slova.org.ru/chernyy/gorodskaiaskazka/) есть строфа:

> Потом у Калинкина моста
>   Смотрела своих *венеричек*.
>   Устала: их было доста.
>   Что с вами? Вы ищете спичек?

В каком значении здесь употреблено слово *венеричка*?

Comment: И еще. Посмотрел по разным источникам. Нигде больше "до ста" (т. е.. "до сотни") слитно не пишется. Мне с самого начала глаз резануло... Хотя в принципе возможно значение "доста" = достаточно, но уж очень тут диссонирует народное просторечие с образованной речью героев.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Больная венерической болезнью. 
Другое дело, что это может быть и переносным значением (=проститутка, скажем), но это надо уже по контексту смотреть. Сашу Черного я люблю, но стихотворение у меня не на слуху, сейчас найду - посмотрю.

А вы бы ссылочки давали, что ли, в таких-то случаях, когда по одному фрагменту очевидно не восстанавливается.

//----
Здесь - проститутки. Я угадал.
Вообще проститутки обязательно осматривались врачом, что удостоверялось записью в "желтом билете". Подозреваю, что в обязанности медичек (студенток медицинских курсов - эти курсы сами по себе штука весьма интересная, учитывая общий подход к женскому образованию в России, но здесь я опускаю) входило ассистирование врачу - или даже самостоятельный осмотр.

Answer (score 3):

Слушайте, вопрос меня не отпускает.

Появилась версия, что это и не проститутки вовсе, а вполне реальные больные.

> [image: фото]
>
> colonelrabin Aug. 24th, 2009 09:05 pm (UTC) Слушайте, а еще какая-то
>   старая больница там есть? Потому что маловероятно, что
>   курсистка-медичка из юмористического стишка Саши Черного, которая
>   "Потом у Калинкина моста / Смотрела своих венеричек", делала это в
>   Военно-Морском госпитале.
>
> Link Reply Thread dm_tolstyh Aug. 24th, 2009
>   09:37 pm (UTC) Там их полно. Снимал я по пути в большой Гериатрический
>   центр, где мама ещё работает. Рядом старый и новый корпус больницы
>   им.Чудновского, на другом берегу ведомственная (ж/д?)поликлинника.
>   Многое наверное в тех стенах было за годы.
>
> Там и квартира Блока в двух шагах.

Всё — отсюда:
[**Питер. Несколько снимков у Калинкина моста**](http://dm-tolstyh.livejournal.com/41330.html)

И вот подтверждение.

> В конце нашего маршрута расположены корпуса бывшей Калинкинской
>   больницы (наб. Фонтанки, 166). Она занимает довольно большой
>   прямоугольный участок, ограниченный с севера Фонтанкой, с запада
>   Либавским переулком, 2-6, а с двух других сторон примыкает к соседним
>   территориям (формально имеется еще адрес по Рижскому пр., 41).
>   ...
>
> На этом месте при Петре I была устроена прядильная фабрика, служившая
>   исправительным заведением для женщин легкого поведения. В 1779 г.
>   вместо фабрики была учреждена "секретная" больница для больных
>   венерическими заболеваниями (официальной датой открытия больницы
>   считается 1781 год). Попасть в эту больницу считалось позором. В 1830
>   - 1833 гг. комплекс больницы был реконструирован по проекту Л.И.Шарлеманя 2-го.
>
> ...
>
> Больница
>   существовала до 1930 г., а затем в ее зданиях разместился
>   научно-исследовательский институт.
>
> Корпус, выходящий непосредственно на набережную Фонтанки:
>
> [image: фото]

[**ФОНТАНКА** | photoprogulki.narod.ru](http://photoprogulki.narod.ru/spb_fontanka52.htm)

Вон оно как... Стыд-то какой, не знать таких вещей))) А это история. 
Но мне простительно, я не петербуржец.
Спасибо Саше Черному и автору вопроса за увлекательнейший экскурс в историю Петербурга.